# ANSI application and Vietnam Codepage

Tags: delphi, localization, delphi-7

---

1. I ve changed the codepage of my system to Russian as explained on [this site](http://www.sisulizer.com/localization/support/codepages-w7.shtml)
2. PC is rebooted
3. Then, I created a file in a dir with a name containing special russian character
4. Then, I ve listed all files in this dir and tried to show the file with typical Delphi 7 code using:

---

```
 SearchRec: TSearchRec;

  FindFirst

  showmessage(SearchRec.Name);

  FindNext(SearchRec);
  FindClose(SearchRec);
```

The code works well.

When I redo all 4 steps with Vietnamese instead of Russian, the filename shown with showmessage is not correct. Some `?` appear instead (see the screenshot):

[image]

Please help

Comment: Do you have a font installed which can display the missing characters?

Comment: I use "showmessage". I don't know what font is used.
However I presume that this is a typical windows font able to display Vietnamese characters

Comment: Your `ShowMessage` function cannot speak Unicode ;-) And the `TSearchRec` as well I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way Delphi versions prior to 2009 implements their `string` type. It is not a problem of font, but a problem of character encoding.

All `string` variables, and also all Windows API calls are performed using ANSI encoding. With ANSI, you can use only one code page at a time. In order to *mix* code pages (i.e. mix russian and vietnamese encodings), you'll need to process the text and call UNICODE Windows API.

Here is what occurred in your case:

- You create a file with russian characters by Windows, using UNICODE encoding;
- When you read the file using vietnamese current code page, only the first 127 characters (i.e. ASCII seven chars, e.g. numbers, main punctuations and English letters), are able to be read from UNICODE into ANSI vietnamese: during the conversion, all uncorrect characters are converted as ? in your ANSI vietnamese string.

So you have several workarounds:

- Upgrade to Delphi >= 2009, and your `string` will be UNICODE, so you will be able to mix character sets;
- Use `widestring` for storing your text, and call directly the windows wide APIs - that is, you can't use the VCL units nor `FindFirst/FindNext` as defined in `SysUtils`, nor `ShowMessage` as defined in `Dialogs`.

Of course, the first one is the easiest!

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. As I understood it, OP changes system codepage to Vietnamese, then creates a file having Vietnamese characters in its name, then finds the file and shows its name.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz The file was created with **russian** characters within its name, not vietnamese. This is what my answer states: it is impossible to read russian characters when the system is switch in vietnamese charset. Both workaround still apply.

Comment: @Arnaud My understanding is that the filename has Vietnamese characters. But I do agree that trying to do the in ANSI is silly. Use Unicode like nature intended.